# Different Barcode numbers By same Barcode line

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

i have take zxing sample project and ran it .But i am surprised to see that scanning same barcode lines 2 times i received different barcode number.My test and images are [image]
plz guide me why is it so.or their is any wrong with code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a misread. It's pretty rare but can happen.